# <Command-a> for Text - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I found the below code :

```
def callback(ev):
    ev.widget.select_range(0, 'end') 

root = Tk()
t = Text(root, height=10, width=40)
t.pack()
t.bind('<Command-a>', callback) //WORKS for ENTRY
root.mainloop()
```

I'm basically trying to make <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (Windows) work for Text in Tkinter.

Error (When I give the command : cmd-a in text):

```
'Text' object has no attribute 'select_range'
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can use "Control"+"a" in a text widget to select all of the text without any additional configuration, is this something which happens on Mac (Assuming you are on Mac), as I am on a windows machine.

Comment: The errror is self-explanatory. Why do you think the text widget has a function named `select_range`?

Answer (score 2):

The code is ok except that you are inventing methods on the Text widget. However, if you look at the bindings on the widget class (Text) there are some virtual events defined

```
>>> '<<SelectAll>>' in root.bind_class('Text')
True
```

So in your handler for the keyboard event, use `event_generate` to raise a SelectAll virtual event.

```
import tkinter as tk
def select_all(ev):
    ev.widget.event_generate('<<SelectAll>>')
root = tk.Tk()
txt = tk.Text(root)
txt.pack()
txt.bind('<Control-A>', select_all)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) class does not have `select_range()` function, that is why you got that error message. But you can use [`bind_class()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html#bind_class) to bind events to the Text class widgets. Here is a dirty demo:

```
import tkinter as tk

def simulate_contral_a(e):
    e.widget.tag_add("sel","1.0","end")

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind_class("Text","<Control-a>", simulate_contral_a)
T = tk.Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(tk.END, "Press Ctrl+a\nto select me\n")
root.mainloop()
```

Run this MCVE above and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to see its effect:

[image]